# escribir una funcion filter que reciba un callback

Tags: javascript

Escribi una función filtrar en el prototipo de Arrays,
que recibe una funcion (callback) que devuelve true o false.
filtrar los elementos de ese arreglo en base al resultado de esa funcion
comparadora, devolver un nuevo arreglo con los elementos filtrados.
NO USAR LA FUNCION FILTER DE LOS ARREGLOS.
cualquier ayuda se agradece

```html
//Ejemplo:

var productos = [{
    price: 100,
    name: 'tv'
  }, {
    price: 50,
    name: 'phone'
  }, {
    price: 30,
    name: 'lamp'
  }]
  productos.filtrar(function(p) {
    return p.price >= 50;
  }) => [{price: 100, name:'tv'}]

//mi codigo
 var produc =[{
edad:26,
nombre: "Naomy"
  },{
edad:33,
nombre: "jony"
  },{
edad:20,
nombre:"Valeria"
  }]
  arrayNuevo = produc.filter(value => value < 30)
  return arrayNuevo
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es agregar una función al `prototype` de la clase `Array` que tome un `callback` y devuelva un nuevo arreglo con los resultados donde el `callback` sean `true`.

La función creará un arreglo vacío, y recorrerá el arreglo original mediante un ciclo `for`. Si el `callback` da `true`, se agregará el elemento al `array` de salida, si da `false`, no se agregará y se pasará al siguiente elemento. Teniendo en cuenta estos requerimientos, una posible implementación sería:

```
Array.prototype.filtrar = function(callback) {
    const resultado = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (callback(this[i])) {
            resultado.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Nota que ahora, los arreglos tendrán esta función como uno más de sus métodos. Aplicada al array producto, quedaría:

```js
Array.prototype.filtrar = function(callback) {
    var resultado = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (callback(this[i])) {
            resultado.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}


var productos = [{
    price: 100,
    name: 'tv'
  }, {
    price: 50,
    name: 'phone'
  }, {
    price: 30,
    name: 'lamp'
  }]

var productosFiltrados = productos.filtrar(function(p) {
  return p.price >= 50;
})

console.log(productosFiltrados)
```